# Style category link depending on category ID

Tags: categories, links, css, id

I want to style a link depending on its ID, for instance, if the category ID is 2, then I want the link to be pink. My theme calls the category like this:

```
<?php if (in_array('categories', get_option('theme_postinfo2'))) { ?> <?php the_category(', ') ?>
```

I found a way to style specific categories in **lists** by adding:

```
li.cat-item-7 { ... }  /* category ID #7, etc */
```

to my stylesheet, however, I cannot find a way to do the same thing to links. What type of solutions are available? Please be detailed in your reply as my coding knowledge is limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the basic way is to

```
 #li.cat-item-7
    { color: red; }
```

Now, change '7' to the number you want, as many times as you want and 'red' to the color you want for that category like -

```
 #li.cat-item-2
    { color: pink; }

    #li.cat-item-8
    { color: green; }
```